# Intellitest integration with existing unit tests

Tags: visual-studio-2015, intellitest

We already had an existing unit test project but Intellitest generates a separate project.  Is there any way to integrate Intellitest into our existing test project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something we would like to do as well. For now, we are tracking this as a feature request here: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/8592451-enable-intellitest-leverage-existing-unit-tests. Kindly consider voting.